# Is this a valid workaround to avoid "invalid use of member ‘X::XX’ in static member function"?

Tags: c++

I was working on someone else's project, and I ran into an issue where the author's static function was preventing me from doing what I wanted. I wanted the function to modify a member variable I had created, which can't happen if the object was never instantiated.

As expected, accessing Foo::number from the static function Foo::foobar() causes this error:

```
staticvspointer.cpp:20:5: error: invalid use of member ‘Foo::number’ in static member function
```

My two options are to make the variable "number" a global, or make the function not static.

```
int NUMBER; //this could be global, but would make the large project messy

//class has a static function
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();
        static int foobar();
        int number;
};

//make member function not static
class Bar {
    public:
        Bar();
        void foobar(int);
        int number;
};

Foo::Foo() {

}

int Foo::foobar() {
    //can't access "number = 2;" in static function.
    NUMBER = 2; //CAN access global though
    return 2;
}

Bar::Bar() {

}

void Bar::foobar(int number) {
    this->number = number;
}

int main() {
    //1.) using a static function to get 2
    int a = Foo::foobar();
    int b = a + 2;
    //b = 4

    //2.) using a pointer to get ClassName::memberVariable, and then deleting it.
    Bar* bar = new Bar;
    bar->foobar(2);
    b = bar->number + 2;
    delete bar;
    //b still = 4

    //3.) using a global
    Foo::foobar();
    b = NUMBER + 2;
    //b = 4 again

    return 0;
}
```

I assume the problems this may or may not cause are dependent on the project, but I can't think of a reason not to do this.

Is there anything wrong with method #2? Is it a proper use of pointers? Is it readable or confusing? For some reason it feels wrong to me.

Comment: Your problem isn't one of access; it's *design* . if your function is static, there is no "there" there regarding non-static member variables. Non-static member variables require an *instance* of the class to exist. So whose `number` was it your intent to modify from a function that, by its declared `static` nature, has no member variables because there is no instance from which to refer to? Unrelated, declaring `bar` as dynamic in `main` is pointless. `Bar bar;` and using `bar.number` thereafter is preferred. Given the posted code, there is no earthly reason to do otherwise.

Comment: You are certainly right about the last part. As for the design question I guess I need to really think about what I am trying to do.There is probably a way I can make their static function do what I want. I am making the program read from a file something that was previously hardcoded, so I can probably do this from the static function just as easily. Design wise I should probably not what I was doing. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making a formerly static function nonstatic. However if the only reason for object creation is making a call to the formerly static function, then perhaps you should make the data in question a function parameter instead, and leave it static.